# Paint 4 rectangles 16px from the 4 corners

Tags: android, android-canvas, drawrect

I will draw 4 squares in a canvas from 16px of distance of the screen corners.
I´m trying with this code:

```
canvas.drawRect(getWidth() - 91,getHeight() - 91, 75, 75, paint);
```

With this code, the square never appears.
How can i draw the 4 squares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code I did pretty fast that ought to help you out & you should be able to optimize

```
    int squareSize =  30;
    int offset = 16;
    // top left
    canvas.drawRect(offset, offset, offset+squareSize, offset+squareSize, paint);
    // top right
    canvas.drawRect(getWidth() - offset - squareSize, offset, getWidth() - offset , offset+squareSize, paint);
    // bottom left
    canvas.drawRect(offset, getHeight() - offset - squareSize, offset+squareSize, getHeight() - offset, paint);
    // bottom right
    canvas.drawRect(getWidth() - offset - squareSize, getHeight() - offset - squareSize, getWidth() - offset , getHeight() - offset, paint);
```

Comment: This answer is good, but the top right square don´t appears.
For top right is   canvas.drawRect(getWidth() - offset - squareSize, offset, getWidth() - offset, offset+squareSize, paint);

Thanks to all.

Comment: @DanielRuiz  Ahh I see what went wrong,  I fixed it in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Should be `getWidth() - 75, getHeight() - 75`.

Notice in the javadoc you have to give top left, bottom, right.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawRect(float, float, float, float, android.graphics.Paint)

Comment: Sorry eduyayo, but i think you don´t understand me. I will draw from 16px from all corners. If the canvas size is for example 960x540, one of these squares should stand in: x=449 , y=869. Anyway, i tried your solution, but no appears squares in the screen.
If i use  down vote favorite
 

I will draw 4 squares in a canvas from 16px of distance of the screen corners. I´m trying with this code:

canvas.drawRect(16,16, 75, 75, paint);  
i can draw one square at this position.